# Interpolate option volatility in delta space in R

Tags: options, implied-volatility, r, volatility-skew, interpolation

I have a bunch of deltas and option implied vols at those deltas. I would like to interpolate them in R. Interpolating them in delta space seems difficult, since normally you would like the ATM calls and puts to paste together, but in delta space they will be on opposite ends of the x-axis (delta). I was thinking of simply doing the following:

```
# first convert everything to moneyness type measure
sample_delta = c(seq(-.5, -.05, by=.05), seq(.05, .55, by=.05))
sample_vols = runif(n = length(sample_delta)) # some made up vols
d1 = ifelse(sample_delta < 0, qnorm(sample_delta +1), qnorm(sample_delta))
s = spline(d1, sample_vols)
```

The issue is that I have to go back and forth converting between `d1` and `delta` when at the end of the day I just want things to be in standardized delta space. Does R have any packages to do this? For example `quantmod` or something of the sort.

To make things more clear: Given a bunch of deltas and implied vols, I would like to generate an entire vol surface. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Just use absolute value of delta?

Comment: Use put call parity to standardize everything to either put deltas or call deltas. If you have a mix of each, pick the convention. For example, if you have -20 delta for the put, it corresponds approximately to a 80 delta call. Note you can't take simply take the absolute value of a negative delta and use it meaningfully in this context. it would imply that C+P=S-K, when in reality we have C-P=S-K (taking r=0, q=0) by PC parity.

Comment: moreover you know that this spline will introduce errors: deltas between nodes will not fit into BS

Comment: @user2183336: can't use absolute value of delta becuase the put vol at .45 delta will surely be different than the call vol at .45 delta

Comment: @cf16: could you eleborate? why will deltas in between nodes not work? i realize it's not an arb free framework, is that what you mean?

Comment: the question isn't obviously that clear... no one is sure really what your trying to accomplish..

Comment: interpolation, linear or cubic or any else  between two delas that are implied, i.e. fit to BS, with respect to time, or strike doesn't yield deltas from BS, because none of these variables is linear function of delta. so ideally you want to get max close to each other real implied deltas and interpolate between them what minimizes the errors

Comment: @cdcaveman: just made a one line statement of the question at the end

Comment: @alex i've done this before.. pulling data from yahoo.. using interp() and rgl package.. .

Comment: @cdcaveman: why do you need rgl? can you provide an answer to the question so we can discuss specifics instead of speaking abstractly?

Comment: @alex .. sorry..  take a look at this thread.. this code works..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725496/fixing-interpolation-over-volatility-surface-graph-in-r-programming

Comment: @cdcaveman if your goal is simply to smoothen the jaggedness of the 3d plot use kernel smoothing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoother there are R packages that help with that.